# At what point can I run the RecordCount to give me the correct number of records

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a subform inside. I need to know how many records the subform has at the start.

My problem is that when I try to get them with RecordSet.RecordCount, the answer is less records than expected.

It is clear that at the moment I try the RecordCount, the subform is not fully loaded yet.

I can't use .RecordsetClone.RecordCount, because the child form is hooked to the parent form, so RecordsetClone asks me for a parameter

The question is: At what point can I run the RecordCount to give me the correct number of records?

Comment: How are you opening that recordset, can you use a client-side cursor? `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient`, and then `rs.Open sql,, adOpenStatic` - with all records loaded client-side from the start, `RecordCount` returns the expected number of records. If you use a server-side cursor, then you need to access all records first - `.MoveLast` does that, but then `.MoveLast` followed by `.MoveFirst` does read funny.

Answer (score 1):

In order to "force" all records to be loaded to get an accurate count, you need to do `.MoveLast` (followed by `.MoveFirst`):

```
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
Debug.Print rs.RecordCount
```

Regards,

Comment: Isn't possible to assign to a recordset, because SubForm has fields that DAO can't undestand, as [Forms]![FrmPrincipal]... etc

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the *OnCurrent* event of the main form:

```
RecordCount = Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount
```